# std::string to char array and char array to string (c++)

Tags: c++, arrays, string

Right now in my current project i have a string like this :

```
std::string ordre="0x010x030x000x320x000x01";
```

And i would like to create a char array looking like this with it (and if possible the reverse action too) :

```
unsigned char Com[]= {0x01, 0x03, 0x00, 0x32, 0x00, 0x01};
```

I have no problem working with the string, creating another std::string and getting the 0x01 part in the beginning using ordre.at() for the characters i want. But i can't find a way to put this new string 0x01 into Com[1].

Writing directly :

```
Com[1]=0x01;
```

It works but i would like to make something where Com[1] could change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use C++ : use STL structures instead of (strugling with) arrays

If I where you i'll build a `std::vector<unsigned char>` and fill it dynamically by iterating over the `x` in the loop.

I would do the vector filling as such:

**Note: This code work ith any size input and is not limited to 4 chars substrings. It is therefore more general but less efficient then the other answers code. Choose according to your needs**

```
std::string order = "0x010x020x030x2360x10240x9001";
std::vector<int> coms;

size_t pos = 0, it;
while ((it = order.find("0x", pos + 1)) != std::string::npos)
{
    coms.push_back(std::stoi(order.substr(pos, it-pos), 0, 16));
    pos = it;
}
coms.push_back(std::stoi(order.substr(pos), 0, 16));
```

gives:

```
0x01 = 1
0x02 = 2
0x03 = 3
0x236 = 556
0x1024 = 4132
0x9001 = 36865
```

Comment: Seems like str and stoi are not declared in the libraries i have.  I have right now : #include <iostream>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <sstream>
#include <string> but i gives me and error : 'str' was not declared in this scope.

Comment: he renamed ordre to str. It's just the variable name. You can change it back.

Comment: I used `str` in a previous version of this answer, before changing the name to `order` to fit the question.
`str` should therefore be replaced by `order`. This code works with just <string> and <array>

Comment: It looks like you are using base 10, when the string is base 16

Comment: Yes, i saw the modification and changed the name back to "ordre". But stoi seems to not be enabled here : stoi not a member of std.

Comment: `std::stoi` is defined in `#include<string>`

Comment: better.  I can crash it with "0x010x"

Comment: @KennyOstrom I assumes the string is correctly formated (you can also crash it with string starting the wrong way). Making it fool proof would require regexp ... with I believe to be overkill here

Answer (score 2):

> Right now in my current project i have a string like this :

```
std::string ordre="0x010x030x000x320x000x01";
```

> And i would like to create a char array looking like this with it (and if possible the reverse action too) :

```
unsigned char Com[]= {0x01, 0x03, 0x00, 0x32, 0x00, 0x01};
```

First, "0x01" is different than 0x01. To extract values from the string, you will need to read it in a loop, four characters at a time:

```
if(ordre.size() % 4)
    throw std::runtime_error{ "invalid string length; format is different" };
std::vector<int> values;

auto b = std::begin(ordre);
const auto e = std::end(ordre);
while(b != e)
{
    std::string s{ b, b+4 };
    values.push_back(std::stoi(s, 0, 16));
    b += 4;
}
```

Comment: std::stoi with base 16 answers the question, so points, but why int?  He's working with unsigned char, and you're willing to enforce that in the string length, but then want to store it as int?

Comment: Yes, "0x01" is not the same as 0x01. But the users are entering a string (like 01). I don't think i can create a unsigned char Com[]= 0x; and then add the 01 part after...

Comment: He's converting the string "0x01" using http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol